# Constraining the parameter value range in ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, parametric-functions

I am trying to use `ParametricNDSolve` to solve a set of ODEs, but I want to give a range for the parameter before solving the equations. How can I constrain the range of the parameter that `ParametricNDSolve` should use?

For example, in the equation below, I want to try and solve the ODEs for `a` between 4 and 6 only.

```
ParametricNDSolve[{y'[t] == a y[t], y[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 10}, {a}]
```

Comment: Why? With `sol = y /. ParametricNDSolve[....]` you can just `sol[4]` to have `a=4` and also for other `a` that you're interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question seems to raise a non-issue. The parametric function returned from evaluating

```
 yF = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[t] == a y[t], y[0] == 1}, y, {t, 0, 10}, {a}]
```

is good for any value of `a` in your range of interest. This is demonstrated by

```
LogPlot[Evaluate @ Table[yF[a][t], {a, 4, 6, .5}], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

If, for further calculations, you have the need to constrain evaluation to `a` in the stated range, you can derive a constrained family of functions like so:

```
yCF[a_ /; 4 <= a <= 6] := YF[a]
```

`yCF` will only accept parameter values in stated range and return unevaluated for any other values.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now if I have the code below: `d = {{9.721036901*10^-7, 0.80119823*10^-6}, {9.728704323*10^-7, 
    0.83015194*10^-6}, {9.728577185000001*10^-7, 
    0.857031534*10^-6},{9.728430487000002*10^-7, 
    0.88804645*10^-6},` `{9.733506242*10^-7, 
    0.914930348*10^-6}, {9.733359543*10^-7, 0.945945264*10^-6}};`
`b = Interpolation[d, InterpolationOrder -> 1];`
`bb = b[a]*10^-4;`
`yF = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[t] == bb y[t], y[0] == 1}, 
  y, {t, 0, 10}, {a}]`, Mathematica is solving the DE but Ican't plot anything.

Comment: @math_enthusiast. That is an entirely different question. You need to post it as new question.